# Scipy Optimize minimize returns the initial value

Tags: optimization, scipy, decision-tree, minimization

I am building machine learning models for a certain data set. Then, based on the constraints and bounds for the outputs and inputs, I am trying to find the input parameters for the most minimized answer. 
The problem which I am facing is that, when the model is a linear regression model or something like lasso, the minimization works perfectly fine. 
However, when the model is "Decision Tree", it constantly returns the very initial value that is given to it. So basically, it does not enforce the constraints.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from scipy.optimize import minimize
```

I am using the very first sample from the input data set for the optimization. As it is only one sample, I need to reshape it to (1,-1) as well.

```
x = df_in.iloc[0,:]
x = np.array(x)
x = x.reshape(1,-1)
```

This is my Objective function:

```
def objective(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    x = x.reshape(1,-1)
    y = 0 
    for n in range(df_out.shape[1]):
        y = Model[n].predict(x)

    Y = y[0]
    return Y
```

Here I am defining the bounds of inputs:

```
range_max = pd.DataFrame(range_max)
range_min = pd.DataFrame(range_min)
B_max=[]
B_min =[]
for i in range(range_max.shape[0]):
    b_max = range_max.iloc[i]
    b_min = range_min.iloc[i]
    B_max.append(b_max)
    B_min.append(b_min)

B_max = pd.DataFrame(B_max)
B_min = pd.DataFrame(B_min)

bnds = pd.concat([B_min, B_max], axis=1)
```

These are my constraints:

```
con_min = pd.DataFrame(c_min)
con_max = pd.DataFrame(c_max)
```

Here I am defining the constraint function:

```
def const(x):
    x = np.array(x)
    x = x.reshape(1,-1)

    Y = []
    for n in range(df_out.shape[1]):
        y = Model[n].predict(x)[0]

        Y.append(y)

    Y = pd.DataFrame(Y)

    a4 =[]
    for k in range(Y.shape[0]):
        a1 = Y.iloc[k,0] - con_min.iloc[k,0]
        a2 = con_max.iloc[k, 0] - Y.iloc[k,0]
        a3 = [a2,a1]
        a4 = np.concatenate([a4, a3])

    return a4


c = const(x)
con = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': const}
```

This is where I try to minimize. I do not pick a method as the automatically picked model has worked so far.

```
sol = minimize(fun = objective, x0=x,constraints=con, bounds=bnds)
```

So the actual constraints are:

```
c_min = [0.20,1000]
c_max = [0.3,1600]
```

and the max and min range for the boundaries are:

```
range_max = [285,200,8,85,0.04,1.6,10,3.5,20,-5]
range_min = [215,170,-1,60,0,1,6,2.5,16,-18]
```

Comment: Can you share plots of objective and constraint w.r.t x?

Comment: I added the constraints and ranges to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the output of 'sol'. At times, the algorithm is not able to perform line search completely. To check for this, you should check message associated with 'sol'. In such a case, the optimizer returns initial parameters itself. There may be various reasons of this behavior. In a nutshell, please check the output of sol and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Arad,

If you have not yet resolved your issue, try using scipy.optimize.differential_evolution instead of scipy.optimize.minimize.  I ran into similar issues, particularly with decision trees because of their step-like behavior resulting in infinite gradients.